# Updating database from dataset in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have read all similar threads and I think I replicate the samples but the code still does not work

bind the grid:

```
sql="select * from myTable";
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,dbConnection._connection);   
adp.Fill(ds);
ds.AcceptChanges();
grdTable.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Save data (on double-click here for simplicity, can be on button click)

```
private void grdTable_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  adp.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

The data is displayed fine but the update statement gives an error: 
"Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."

All examples that I saw did not require creating UpdateCommand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an OleDbCommandBuilder that automatically generates the commands for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

```
sql = "select * from myTable";
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adp.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConnection._connection);
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp);
adp.Fill(ds);
ds.AcceptChanges();
grdTable.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Please refer to the above MSDN link for more information.